# How do I keep single quotes intact when returning the output of a Bash subshell to the OSX "defaults" utility?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, escaping, quotes

**Context/Goal:**

I'm trying to write an array to a key in a .plist file via the OSX `defaults` utility. My goal is to rewrite the array with contents of my choosing, not to modify its existing contents. The new contents are the product of another command, and are supposed to be single-quoted, space-separated strings in the shell, each one corresponding to an array element.

I have `bash` 3.2.57, and OSX 10.10.

**Problem:**

I can't seem to get bash's quote-literal expansion to work right. I've simplified the command I'm using via a subshell to an `echo` in these examples. The problematic behavior is the same.

For example, if I write the whole array like so:

```
/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras -array 'foo bar' 'baz quux'
```

I can read it out, like so:

```
/usr/bin/defaults read com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras
(
    "foo bar",
    "baz quux"
)
```

The `defaults` utility adds the double-quotes.

That's fine. However, if I use a subshell to generate the array contents, things go wrong:

```
/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras -array $( echo -e 'foo bar' 'baz quux' )
/usr/bin/defaults read com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras
(
    foo,
    bar,
    baz,
    quux
)
```

It detects the space in the string as delimiting the fields. Ok, I thought, maybe that's naïve; Bash will remove single quotes whenever it can, so I need to "hint" that it should keep them around.

I then tried every combination of literal-quote suggestions for Bash I could think of, with the same result. All of the below, if assigned to a variable and `echo`ed, yield `'foo bar'`, with the quotes intact.

```
$( echo -e "'foo bar'" )
$( echo -e "\x27foo bar\x27" )
$( echo -e '\x27foo bar\x27' )
$( echo $'\'foo bar\'' )
$( echo \'foo bar\' )
$( echo \''foo bar'\' )
$( echo "'"'foo bar'"'" )
$( echo ''"'"'foo bar'"'"'' )
```

**Question**:

How can I get a series of single-quoted strings out of a subshell and into a bash command with their quotes intact, so that `defaults` can use it without messing up the field separator and splitting on spaces when it shouldn't?

The subshell will need to be able to return more than one quoted array element. I need to use the shell, and ideally just POSIX shell features (this is part of a larger script). I would prefer to avoid, if possible, hacks like storing things in a temp file or `<(...)` on-demand pipes. The strings also need to be single, not double, quoted, since their contents may at some point contain double quotes, and I don't want to have to fight with quote escaping twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further messing around yielded the answer: `xargs` instead of a subshell:

```
echo \'foo bar\' \'baz quux\' | xargs  /usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras -array
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the expansion:

```
usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras \
                       -array "$( echo 'foo bar' )"
```

(I removed the `-e` argument from the `echo` since it has no effect.)

It's not clear to me what you expect the effect of the `-array` argument to be. Normally you would use it with multiple values:

```
usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras \
                       -array "$(echo 'one two')" \
                              "$(echo 'buckle my shoe')"
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: the expansion is eventually going to return more than one array element. I've updated the question to reflect that.